# Doing simple manual classification of LAS using QGIS

Tags: qgis, lidar, classification, point-cloud, cross-section

Are there any basic tools for lidar classification in QGIS?

Id like to do simple function like reclassing single points, classing points inside a fence or above a line. something similar to the basic tools in TerraSolid. Ideally they could be leveraged in the cross sectional view. Everything I can find is more broad processing based but I'm looking for some manual tools to fine tune the classifications

[image: View of the LAS im working with in Q]

Comment: Have you taken a look at PDAL? https://pdal.io/en/2.7.0/

Comment: Thanks! I have from what I can tell its all command line based and what I'm looking for is some super basic tools, like an inside fence or above line to reclass points within the cross section. Perhaps those exist and I can't find them, though it does seem like PDAL is a good start, I will keep digging there!

Comment: Another good option would be LAStools plugin then.

Comment: I've looked into this one a bit and again seems like its geared towards broad processing with no small scale tools to do simple manual classification. Maybe building a plugin leveraging PDAL is the move.